# ffmpeg how to calculate size from webm to mp3 without conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, filesize, file-conversion, webm

Im using the Linux command "ffmpeg", and i was wondering if there is a solution to calculate theoretically (simulate the conversion) the size without making the conversion from .webm file into .mp3 160k.

Is there a formula or something like that, that I follow to get the size ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you encode your `MP3` with a constant bitrate (`CBR`) then it's very easy:

```
file_size = bitrate * audio_track_duration
```

Let's say your audio track's duration is `1` minute:

```
160 Kb/s * 60 s = 9600 Kb
9600 Kb / 8 = 1200 KB = 1.2 MB
```

You can get the audio stream durations with `ffprobe` (they may be inaccurate in some cases):

```
ffprobe -i <input> -select_streams a -show_entries stream=duration -of default=nk=1:nw=1 -v quiet
```

Comment: Thank you for this very good answer. Can you tell me why did you divided by 8 ?

Comment: @YoussefElGharbaoui `Kb` is kilobits. One byte has 8 bits.

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you so much. (I really needed the ffprobe solution you just gave me, thank you @aergistal )

Comment: I just tried the ffprobe command that you gave me, and it outputs : N/A, im giving it the full .webm file path, did I make a mistake somewhere ?

Comment: Ive found the solution : ffprobe -v quiet -print_format compact=print_section=0:nokey=1:escape=csv -show_entries format=duration <input>. Thank u